# In unary operator overloading in cpp , how to decide on which side of an object do we need to put operator sign?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, unary-operator

defining function->

```
        car operator *()
        {
            car temp;
            temp.a = a*3;
            temp.b = b*3;
            return temp;
        }
```

in given below code,how to decide whether * is before o2 or after o2.

```
car o3=*o2  //o2 is also an object of same class and has some values for a and b
```

Comment: Unary `*` is the dereference operator, it's _always_ on the left side of the thing you want to dereference. What would be the alternative? I'm not 100% sure what you are asking.

Comment: If you write `o2*`, you will get a syntax error, and if you write `*o2`, you won't. The only unary postfix operators are the increment and decrement operators.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one unary operator that can appear on either side of an object. It is disambiguated by providing two overloads: one that takes only one argument and one that takes an `int` as its second argument. The compiler knows about that, and calls it appropriately:

```
struct S {
    S& operator++();    // pre-increment
    S operator++(int);  // post-increment
};

S s;
++s; // calls S::operator++()
s++; // calls S::operator++(int)
```

Yes, that extra argument is a hack. No, you can't do anything meaningful with its value.

All the other unary operators that can be overloaded appear in the same place as the non-overloaded version. If the operator goes in front of the object in a non-overloaded context (e.g., *ptr), then it goes in front of the object in an overloaded context (e.g., *my_object). If it comes after, it comes after.